# C# XML and ListVies application

Tags: c#, xml, listview

G'day.

I just want to write a simple application about XML and ListView Control with C#.
Any good tutorial? thank you!

Comment: Hi. You should ask real questions here ("I have ..., I need ..., I tried it with ..., what do I do wrong?"), or your question will get closed in no time. No offense, but looking for generic tutorials is what Google has been made for. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple? With XML? And a ListView? Good luck.

However, [this link](http://file:///C:/jpp/code/cs/ObjectListView/SourceForge/website/cs/gettingStarted.html) shows how to start using an [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx), which is a wrapper around a standard .NET WinForms ListView. In the demo of ObjectListView, the "Data" tab show how to load an XML file into a DataSet, and then show that DataSet in a DataListView (which is a data bindable version of an ObjectListView).

That should be a start, at least.